# Runtime error '91' referencing a range to generate Outlook emails

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to generate four Outlook emails.

I got this error:

> runtime error 91

at: `rng = "rng" & i`.

```vb
Sub generate4emails()

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range

Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:F14")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:F18")
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H12:K14")
Set rng4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H16:K18")

For i = 1 To 4
    Set Outappp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.Createitem(0)
    rng = "rng" & i
    
    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        .Subject = "Notice" & i
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
Next i   
End Sub
```

Comment: You declared it as a range, you are trying to assign a string.

Comment: What do you expect from this line: `rng = "rng" & i`? A range must be `Set`. Do you want building a variable from a string and a number? If so, this is not possible.

Comment: I wanted to generate four emails with 4 different ranges in the sheet, so I wanted to refer to the four range addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your ranges as array instead of multiple variables so you can loop through that array:

```
Sub generate4emails()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng(1 To 4) As Range
    
    Set rng(1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:F14")
    Set rng(2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:F18")
    Set rng(3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H12:K14")
    Set rng(4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H16:K18")
    
    For i = 1 To 4
        Set Outappp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.Createitem(0)
        
        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
            .Subject = "Notice" & i
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng(i))
            .display
        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i   
End Sub
```

Note, when ever you have the feeling you need to number your variables you can be sure you are doing it wrong. Always use arrays instead.

---

You can even improve this to a minimum:

```
Sub generate4emails()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Dim RngAddresses As Variant
    RngAddresses = Array("C12:F14", "C16:F18", "H12:K14", "H16:K18")
    
    For i = LBound(RngAddresses) To UBound(RngAddresses)
        Set Outappp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.Createitem(0)
        
        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
            .Subject = "Notice" & i + 1
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(RngAddresses(i))
            .display
        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i   
End Sub
```

Note that if you generate an array with `Array()` it starts counting with `0` not with `1`!

Comment: I like your comment regarding numbering of variables :-) With this code it would even be possible to only store the addresses in an array, e.g. arrAdresses, store `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`in `wsSheet1` and then use `RangeToHTML(wsSheet1.range(arrAdresses(i)))`

Comment: @Ike yes, using `Array()` you can even reduce it to a minimum. See my edit.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you sososososo much! I finally understand what was wrong!!

Comment: @qiao I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answers our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next adapted way:

```
Sub generate4emails()

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, arrRng

Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:F14")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:F18")
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H12:K14")
Set rng4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H16:K18")
arrRng = Array(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrRng)
    Set Outappp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set rng = arrRng(i)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
        .Subject = "Notice" & i
        .HtmlBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why so complicated `arrRng = Array(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4)` an not `Dim rng(1 To 4) As Range` directly?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I only (rapidly) adapted his code **as it was**. No new declaration, only a code line in plus and a modified one... :) Everything identic with the original code. I felt he needs understanding why the mistake and I tried supplying a didactic answer. :) I don't know if this was the best choice.